# Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, if $m(x)$ is a polynomial of $I$ with the smallest degree, how can we prove $(m(x))\subset I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, if $m(x)$ is a polynomial of $I$ with the smallest degree, how can we prove $(m(x))\subset I$?

For the additive part, it is easy. But for the multiplicative part, we need to pick $r$ from $R$ first. If $r$ is a constant, that will be clear. But can $r$ be polynomial? If so, how can we promise $(m(x))$ must be a subset of $I$?

Comment: What is a 'polynomial of an ideal'? Doesn't it happen that $R$ itself is a polynomial ring?

Comment: Oh, that's true. So the polynomials in $I$ have a highest degree, say $n$. If we keep multiplying $m(x)$ by $r(x)$, then their degree will finally greater than $n$, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you refer $I$ as an ideal of $R[x]$ and not $R$.
In general if $m(x)\in I$ then  $(m(x))\subset I$ because $f(x)m(x) $ is a moltiplication of an element of the ideal $I$ with an element of $R[x]$ and so it belongs to $I$.
The most interesting question is if it is possibile to get $(m(x))=I$.
In general is not true for example in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ the ideal $I=(x^2+1,2)$ is different by $(2)$ and so you have only $(2)\subset I$.

You can think that the problem in this case is that you can’t divide $x^2+1$ for $2$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a Field and you can’t write his inverse.
You can proof that if $R$ is a Field than $R[x]$ is a PID and so you have always that $(m(x))=I$.